# NullPointerException ftp.stop() FakeFtpServer/mockFTPServer

Tags: java, mocking, junit4

I have a failure in my JUnit testing testing trace.
The error is java.lang.NullPointerException and it occurs into these line of code:

```
    @AfterClass
public static void after()
{
    stopServer();
}
```

and

```
static void stopServer()
{
    ftp.stop();
}
```

What I want to do is to have my @AfterClass to stop my fakeFTPServer, initiate into the @BeforeClass

```
    @BeforeClass
public static void before()
{
    FakeFtpServer ftp = new FakeFtpServer();

    ftp.addUserAccount(new UserAccount("user", "password", "c:\\data"));
    FileSystem fileSystem = new WindowsFakeFileSystem();
    fileSystem.add(new DirectoryEntry("c:\\data"));
    fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("c:\\data\\file1.txt", "abcdef 1234567890"));
    fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("c:\\data\\run.exe"));
    ftp.setFileSystem(fileSystem);

    ftp.start();

    ftpClient = new FTPClient();}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have more than one variable named `ftp`.

This is one of them:

```
FakeFtpServer ftp = new FakeFtpServer();
```

This `ftp` is local to `before()` and therefore can't be the variable referenced in `stopServer()`. The latter must be using a different variable named `ftp`, which nevers get initialized. At a guess, that other `ftp` is a static member of your class.

I suspect the above line was meant to read:

```
ftp = new FakeFtpServer();
```

Comment: You're right! That was the issue, FakeFtpServer ftp was already declared.

Comment: @plog17: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem. For more info, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work